# How to make the application close if splash activity is closed in Android

Tags: android

I have a splash activity that is displayed for 2 seconds before opening the main activity.
If the user presses the back button while the splash activity is being displayed, the splash activity closes. But a short time later, the main activity [which was triggered by the splash activity] opens up.

I don't want this to happen. I want the entire application to close if the back button is pressed while the splash screen is being displayed. 
How do I accomplish this?

Edit:
below is my code for splash activity:

```
    public class Splash2 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // fullscreen
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        // fading transition between activities
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash2);
        Thread timer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(1500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Intent open = new Intent(
                            "com.example.puzzletimer.HOMESCREEN");
                    startActivity(open);
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this code to your SplashActivity...

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```

or maintain one flag to determine to start Activity or not in Thread...

```
public class Splash2 extends Activity {

    private volatile boolean interrupt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // fullscreen
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        // fading transition between activities
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash2);
        Thread timer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(1500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (!interrupt) {
                        Intent open = new Intent(
                                "com.example.puzzletimer.HOMESCREEN");
                        startActivity(open);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        interrupt = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
// do something on back.
this.finish();
return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is with runnable:

1. Declare Handler and Runnable in your Splash2 activity:

   ```
   private Handler handler;
   private Runnable startMain;
   ```
2. In onCreate(), initialize them and set the runnable to fire in 1.5 secs:

   ```
   handler = new Handler();
   startMain = new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           Intent open = new Intent("com.example.puzzletimer.HOMESCREEN");
           startActivity(open);
       }
   };      

   handler.postDelayed(startMain, 1500);
   ```
3. Override onBackPressed() and simply cancel runnable:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
       handler.removeCallbacks(startMain);
       super.onBackPressed();
   }
   ```

That's it. If back key is pressed, it cancels runnable and your homescreen won't run.